# pivot "deleted" event when parent is deleted

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 models: `User` and `Role`.

A user can have many roles.

A role can have many users.

I have a custom pivot model between these 2 models. This custom pivot model only exists because it uses a trait that listens/logs for events such as `created`, `updated`, `deleted`.

Let's say I have a role called `moderator`. When I `attach()` (or `detach()`) that role to 5 users, it does successfully fire 5 `created` (or `deleted`) events for the pivot table.

```php
$roleModerator->users()->attach($anArrayOfFiveUsersHere);
```

So far so good.

My problem is the following: when I delete the `moderator` role itself, it does delete all pivot rows associated to the role, but it does not fire any `deleted` event for each deleted pivot rows.

Expected behavior: I want Laravel to fire `deleted` events for each rows it deletes in the pivot table when I ask it to delete the role.

Environment: PHP 7.3 / Laravel 6

One weird thing I noticed, if I add this to my `Role` model :

```php
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function (self $model)
        {
            //$model->users()->detach(); // <-- this fails firing deleted events.
            //MyCustomPivot::query()->where('role_id', $model->id)->get()->each->delete(); // <-- this fails firing deleted events.
            $model->users()->sync([]); // <--- this works!
        });
    }
```

`sync([])` will work great and fire as many `deleted` events as it deletes pivot rows.

but `detach()`, although it accomplishes the same thing, won't fire any `deleted` event. Why is that? They are both from `InteractisWithPivotTable.php` and `sync()` does even call `detach()` itself!

[image]

Comment: so if you have nothing in your `static::deleting()` method, do the pivot table records remain there?

Comment: my guess is that the `$model->users()->detach();` is actually doing nothing, because the detach() method should accept an array of IDs (as seen in the screenshot on line 110). if the records are being deleted and no events are firing, perhaps your database has a foreign key set to ON_DELETE=CASCADE, and so they are being deleted on the database level, which laravel cannot detect... a long shot maybe but just a thought :)

Comment: If I have nothing in my ```static::deleting()``` method, the pivot table records are still deleted alongside the deletion of the role itself. I do have indeed a cascading constraint on delete ```$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');```

Comment: so to answer the question about why sync() is firing the events but detach() is not, it's because you need to pass IDs into the detach() method for it to work. So you can get all the IDs like `$ids = $model->users()->pluck('id')->toArray()` and then  `$model->users()->detach($ids);` (my syntax may be slightly wrong there but hopefully you get the idea). that will make your detach method fire the events. And yeah the reason events weren't firing in the first place is because MySQL is cascade-deleting them which Laravel cannot detect :)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships ```// Detach all roles from the user...
$user->roles()->detach();```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure it's applicable to your situation, but according to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/415), you need to do some setup in your models.

First, make sure you have a primary key column in your table and defined on your pivot model.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class MyCustomPivot extends Pivot
{
    public $primaryKey   = "id";
    public $incrementing = true;
}
```

Second, make sure you include your custom pivot model in your relationships.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
            ->using(MyCustomPivot::class)
            ->withPivot('id');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
            ->using(MyCustomPivot::class)
            ->withPivot('id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that issue on GH via GG as well before I decided to ask SO. That was not useful sadly. I very doubt it matters, but maybe I should precise this is a ```morphedByMany``` / ```morphToMany``` relation. Pivot extends ```MorphPivot```.

Comment: Might be helpful to add the **relevant** code from your models to the question, especially relationships. Another option might be using the model's `boot()` method to do everything you need doing (fire the event, delete the relationships, etc.)